# Authentication using Blogger account always fails the first time

Tags: bug, feedback, blogger

I am login in stackoverflow.com by blogger. I see a thing everytime when I login. I see the same thing from 2-3 months.

If I write blog url and press login then first time I see "woops something goes wrong on my blogger page". I press back and press on button again then it's work fine.

Can someone let me know where thing goes wrong in this case.

---

After type my blog url in stackoverflow.com I have redirect to Blogger.com (I am tried from India). I got the message something like "Woopse Something goes ". This is happen usually on stackoverflow.com when I try to login on stackoverflow.com.

For get login I press back button and click on button again. They will redirect me again and it's make it work fine.

I have tried it in Chrome latest. When I tried to show screenshot from Incognito I have got login worked in first try.

Comment: *I see **a thing** everytime when I login* ... what do you see?

Comment: Could you perhaps try to replicate the issue, take a screenshot and add it to your question?

Comment: Just tried with my blogger account and it works just fine. Can you provide the URL you entered and the exact error message (or better, a screenshot)?

Comment: *I see a thing everytime when I login*. That means you need to do some stuff, that will correct this.

Comment: next time when it's happen I will show you a screenshot. Thanks for now.